# Change position of prev/next nav in Nivo Slider

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I'm using the Nivo Slider jquery plugin, and for the most part it's good. I was able to do some styling on my own (i.e. change the frame around the images, change the caption positioning, etc.), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the position of the next/previous arrows.

I want to have the arrows displayed at the right of the caption bar:

[image]

Is this possible? I've fiddled with the background:position values in .theme-default a.nivo-nextNav (and prevNav), but can't seem to get it where I want it.

**Edited to add CSS**

This is the existing CSS for the navigation buttons:

```
theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0; 
    right:15px;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}
```

It produces arrows positioned like this:

[image]

Comment: please provide the code/fiddle so we can see where is the issue or how to accomplish this.

Comment: `background-position:` is not how you move elements around... it's used for shifting the background image around _within_ the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible - have you tried altering the "top" "left" and "right" css values? One of the arrows should have top/left while the other will have top/right (those are the default settings at least). Those are used to determine the positioning of the nav arrows, whereas background-position refers to the image sprite (for hover effects and the like).

**EDIT**

Try using this CSS:

```
.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-nextNav {
    top:500px; //you'll need to tweak the top and right values to get it into proper position
    right: 300px;
}
.theme-default a.nivo-prevNav {
    top: 500px; // again, tweak these to fit your layout
    left:250px;
}
```

It might be possible within Nivo Slider to choose where you want the navigation html markup to go. In that case you could place it within the caption box and then position it relatively (similar to how it currently works within the overall slider). If not, this CSS solution should work.

Comment: Nope; none of them do. Adding the existing css to the OP.

Comment: The right and left values are there, but in this example the navigation is relatively positioned inside of the slider. That is why the nextNav has right:15px (it is 15px to the right of the edge of the slider) and vice versa for he prevNav. If you want it to be positioned on the right of the caption bar, my suggestion would be to position it absolutely. I'll edit my original answer with sample code.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed most of the lines in the nivo-directionNav a definition? There's now no actual URL for the images that are being used in your code.

Comment: I meant for you to add my lines to the existing ones, not replace it entirely. I'll update my answer accordingly.